# Problems passing system properties using maven 3.0.1

Tags: java, properties, maven

I'm using maven 3.0.1 in ubuntu 10.10, I'm trying to do:

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Dfoo=bar"
mvn clean install
```

And my build does not work. However, when I do

```
mvn clean install -Dfoo=bar
```

It works.

Does anyone have any idea why this happens?

Comment: The same problem occurs when I tried to use maven 3.0.2...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maven doesn't use `JAVA_OPTS` but uses `MAVEN_OPTS` for the same purpose.

Comment: it's strange though, in maven 2 this used to work... They lost compatibility there.

Comment: looking at `mvn` source from 2.2.1 doesn't seem it used `JAVA_OPTS` either.